# how would we automate the execution of the tests

Tags: c#, tfs, nunit

how would we automate the execution of the tests.Is there a better way to do this than a Windows Scheduled Tasks? we are using TFS for CI and NUnit for testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [build task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) to run the tests.

There is a bunch of extra community tasks [here](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).

And [a blog post](http://www.zorched.net/2006/11/28/msbuild-with-nunit/) explaining how to setup MSBuild with nUnit.

Answer (score 2):

NUNIT command line option can be used in the Post Build event to run the assiciated test when the project compiles.

Comment: This runs every time the project  compiles. If I am not wrong. But i want the test to  run only at scheduled time.

Comment: Hi Karthik,can you tell me how to associate Nunit with post build event to run the associated test when the project compiles.